# Citrix-hypervisor VS Xenserver

Tags: virtualization, xen, citrix, hypervisor, xenserver

What's the difference between **citrix-hypervisor** and **xenserver** ?

On the official [website](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-hypervisor/product-software/) of citrix, you can see they provide both softwares, but i feel like it does the exa

ct same thing, but then why call them differently and provide both?
This is very confusing.

Comment: XenServer is a type-1 ("bare metal") hypervisor, like VMware ESXi. That means there is no GUI OS like Windows or macOS, there is just the base-level OS that runs the VMs. 

No idea on "Citrix-hypervisor" as I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between citrix-hypervisor and xenserver ?

There is no difference.  Xenserver was the previous version of Citrix Hypervisor.

> you can see they provide both softwares, but i feel like it does the exact same thing, but then why call them differently and provide both?

Xenserver last version was 7.6 while the 8.0 version of the same Hypervisor is now called Citrix Hypervisor.  Citrix supports multiple versions of their Hypervisor and currently only have one long term service release.

[image]

Source: [Here](https://www.citrix.com/products/)

Answer (score 2):

Citrix Hypervisor is the new name of XenServer, starting at **Citrix Hypervisor 8.0**.  The previous version was **XenServer 7.6**.

> The technology you trust from XenServer, the high-performance hypervisor optimized for virtual app and desktop workloads and based on the Xen Project hypervisor, is now Citrix Hypervisor.

<sup><sub>Source: [https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenserver](https://web.archive.org/web/20190505105344/https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenserver)</sub></sup>

They are not the quite same thing.  In other words, XenServer is the name for older versions (7.6 and earlier) while Citrix Hypervisor is the name for newer versions (since 8.0).